# Is sizeof(<variable>) instead of sizeof(<type>) always safe?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I know that I can protect myself by writing

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof (*ptr))
```

instead of

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof (int))
```

The benefit is that if you decide to change the type of `ptr` to for instance `long*` instead of `int*`, then you only need to change the code at one place.

My question is, is this strategy always safe to do? Is there any situation where the construct `T *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` would not work? Does it matter if `T` is some complex struct, pointer to pointer, function pointer or an array? Or a combination of them for that matter.

I have tried to come up with a situation where it causes problems, but to me it seems safe. But I want to be able to trust the code completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case I could see causing problems is if `*ptr` has a variable-length array type, because that's the only case where `sizeof` evaluates its operand.

That is:

```
int n = ...;
T (*ptr)[n] = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

has undefined behavior because the type of `*ptr` is `T [n]`, which is a variable-length array type, which means `sizeof` evaluates its operand, which dereferences an uninitialized pointer (`*ptr`).

However, it's hard to run into that issue by accident. Normally you'd just do

```
T *ptr = malloc(n * sizeof *ptr);
```

which is fine<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, the multiplication might overflow. To protect against that, you need something like `T *ptr = calloc(n, sizeof *ptr);`.

Comment: It would not be very hard to do it by accident. You could have `int (*matrix)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't think I've ever seen code like that "in the wild".

Comment: Although your analysis the first issue is technically correct, I would say that it's a defect in the standard and in practice it is safe to use the construct.  Also, there is debate over whether `calloc` actually protects against overflow or not; and common library implementations do just multiply the operands and call malloc.

Comment: @M.M Those libraries are broken, I'd say. I don't see where the standard allows for `calloc` to just silently allocate the wrong amount of memory.

Comment: @melpomene: It is in the same place that says a stack overflow may occur, C 2018 5.2.4 1: “Both the translation and execution environments constrain the implementation of language translators and libraries.”

Comment: @melpomene regardless of one's view on that brokenness, in terms of practical programming one must be aware that common implementations do work that way

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't see how that section allows for stack overflow; it only lists translation limits and numerical limits. There's nothing about a maximum nesting depth of function calls. And it says "*the library-related limits are
discussed in clause 7*", but clause 7 says nothing about `calloc` being allowed to silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: @melpomene: The execution environment, which has a finite number of bits for the stack pointer, and for other things, constrains the implementation of language translators and libraries. We are not able to make a language translator that allows for indefinite recursion. Note that 5.2.4 is not limited to just effects experienced at translation time; 5.2.4.1 says “… be able to translate and execute…” So it is allowing for things that break during execution.

Comment: @melpomene I do not see UB here.

Comment: The standard says that `calloc` "allocates space for an array of `nmemb` objects, each of whose size is `size`" and "returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space", which seems pretty clear to me.  I don't see how 5.2.4 is relevant; by that same token, wouldn't it also be legal for `malloc` to silently allocate the wrong amount of memory?  I don't doubt that quality-of-implementation issues exist in the wild, though.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe, portable  and it is considered as a good practice.

Of course it will not safe if someone will hide pointers in the typedefs and make the code unreadable. But this is considered as a very bad practice.

Function pointers are very specific as they do not need the memory for the object (function)

Comment: Why is it not safe with typedefs?

Comment: @melpomene `typedef int * T;` - and you do not see if the T is a pointer type or not. Easy to forget as there is no star in the actual object declaration/definition

Comment: What's unsafe about that?

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You could give an example of code that has an undesired effect because a mistake was made due to pointers in a type definition.

Comment: How are function pointers “very specific”? Whatever is pointed to has to exist, whether it is a function or an object. In either case, it occupies memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if we consider a portable code the object which function pointer references is created the very specific way. Isn't it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I saw a lot. If you prefer this way of programing - it is up to you but it definitely makes code reviews more challenging :)

Comment: I agree, to hide pointer using a typedef is a very bad idea and is unsafe because helps to introduce errors in the code (so I UV ^^)

Comment: Is this unsafe in the way I'm asking? Is there any situation where `sizeof *x == sizeof (T)` would not evaluate to true if `x` is declared `T *x;`?

Comment: it safe because you change  `T` to `T1` `T1 *x`;` then `sizeof *x != sizeof (T)`. It helps to avoid stupid errors (like a forgotten change from `T` to `T1` in  `sizeof`)